# fbconnect module invite issue

Tags: social-network

This is a test site where i have installed [fbconnect module](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect) I am facing issues while Inviting Friends:

What i am doing:
1. Connect to site through Fbconnect (by clicking on Login with Fb button)
2. Click on Invite Friends link which goes to fbconnect/invite/friends
3. Select Friends i want to invite.
4. Click "Send FB APP NAME Invitation"

Now, the Invited person gets a notification

```
Naushad Shaikh
Invited you to FB APP NAME. Try Now
```

URL Points to : http://www.facebook.com/games#

However nothing happens and the invitation does not succeed as it should.

Please let me know what should i do / what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

After a lot of research, i came to know that the Facebook Application for FbConnect did not have a Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL

So i did below:

1. Added Canvas URL to the Application as domain.com
2. Added Secure Canvas URL as Fb's changed policy required so added https://www.domain.com
3. Now, i could click the Application and it opened In Fb IFRAME,
4. I wanted it to redirect on the website, (NOT ALLOWED AS PER FB TERMS & COS)
5. Solution an Image Pointing to External link (www.domain.com)

Thanks for the viewers of this question. I got a Tumbleweed badge for this question.